# Is it possible to add custom keyboard shortcuts to a webapp which you don't own?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For example, suppose there's a webapp called todotasks.com that allows you to log in and add new tasks (in particular, by clicking a series of menu bottons, inputing text in a popup form, and pressing enter). Suppose this webapp doesn't have a keyboard shortcut for adding a new task, and forces you to do everything with a mouse. Would it be possible to add your own keyboard shortcut here that works locally to your machine?

**NOTE:** Here I'm referring to webapps which you are **not the author of.**

Comment: This should be solvable by appropriate browser plugins. As is, this question is likely to be off-topic on UNIX&Linux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix or Linux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about end-user configuration, not about programming. It should not have been closed on [unix.se].

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev How on earth is this question off-topic on [unix.se]? Configuring applications such as web browsers is definitely on-topic.

Comment: @garethTheRed Assuming that the browser runs on a Unix-like system, which is implied if the question is asked on [unix.se], browser usage *is* on-topic on [unix.se]. But it is off-topic on [so], since the question is not about programming.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, I didn't mean this question should be migrated to SO (all I did was writing the comment), and you're right about it being on-topic on U&L. This being said, the question is missing essential details (particular browser and webapp) and is too broad to be answerable as is. The only answer I can imagine is "write a plugin for your browser to support the webapp you want".